# MVC 4 Rating System

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

sorry that I'm quite new to MVC4.
Im building an mvc4 rating system.

First, i was created a view to input the rating question field and store the info into rating db as below:

```
Rating Question Input
==============================
Question : [ What Fruit You Like? ] 
Sub Question : Apple ; Orange ; Grapes
Number of Radio Button : [3]
Rating Header : Hate ; Like ; Very Like
```

My Ratingdb field:

```
public class RatingInput
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int QuestionId { get; set; }
        public string Question { get; set; }
        public string Subquestion { get; set; }
        public int NumberRadioButton { get; set; }
        public string ratingheader { get; set; }
    }
```

How was the data look like in db :

```
Question             | Subquestion         | NumberRadioButton | ratingheader
What Fruit you Like? | Apple;Orange;Grapes |         3         | Hate;Like;Very Like
```

How do i generate the seperate line in table for the question and radio button?
The illustrate output as below:

```
1. What Fruit You Like ?

                  Hate     Like      Very Like
Apple             []        []          []
Orange            []        []          []
Grapes            []        []          []
```

My Rating Output page code sample :

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Question)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SubQuestion) *Need Help
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NumberRadioButton) *Need Help
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ratingheader) *Need Help
            </td>

        </tr>
    }
```

Comment: Are you wanting to have 3 radio buttons for each fruit?

Comment: Hi Stephen, yes exactly.

Comment: Then you need to create a view model with the properties your need for rendering the view. I'll add an answer in an hour or so

Comment: Thanks alot stephen, is it possible to generate the new line for subquestion by detect the semicolumn? I'm trying for loop to generate the radio button and almost work.. but have no idea for subquestion.

Comment: Have just seen your edit. Your database structure makes no sense at all and does not represent relational data. The `NumberRadioButton` and `ratingheader` fields should be deleted, and you need a separate table for sub-questions that has a `QuestionID` field that is a foreign key to the `QuestionTable` (which should contain only information about the question (its ID, Text etc)

Comment: Hi Stephen, thanks for your clue, will rework on the database structure and upload it later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to create view models to represent what you want to display/edit, which might look like

```
public class SubQuestionVM
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string Text { get; set; }
  public string Rating { get; set; }
}
public class QuestionVM
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string Text { get; set; }
  public List<SubQuestionVM> SubQuestions { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the controller, initialize a new collection of `QuestionVM` and pass it to the view

```
public ActionResult Edit()
{
  List<QuestionVM> model = new List<QuestionVM>();
  // Populate it from the database, but for testing
  model.Add(new QuestionVM()
  {
    ID = 1,
    Text = "What Fruit You Like ?",
    SubQuestions = new List<SubQuestionVM>()
    {
      new SubQuestionVM() { ID = 1, Text = "Apple" }, // include Rating="Hate" (or some value) if you want a default radio button selected
      new SubQuestionVM() { ID = 2, Text = "Orange" },
      new SubQuestionVM() { ID = 3, Text = "Grapes" }
    }
  });
  return View(model);
}
```

and in the view

```
@model List<yourAssembly.QuestionVM>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
  {
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].ID)
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].Text)
    for(int j = 0; j < Model[i].SubQuestions.Count; j++)
    {
      @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].SubQuestions[j].ID)
      @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].SubQuestions[j].Text)
      var id = string.Format("Hate-{0}", Model[i].SubQuestions[j].ID);
      @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m[i].SubQuestions[j].Rating, "Hate", new { id = id })
      <label for="@id">Hate</label>
      id = string.Format("Like-{0}", Model[i].SubQuestions[j].ID);
      @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m[i].SubQuestions[j].Rating, "Like", new { id = id })
      <label for="@id">Like</label>
      // ditto for 'Very Like'
    }
  }
  <input type="submit" />
}
```

and post back to

```
public ActionResult Edit(List<QuestionVM> model)
```

Note: What I have shown here is only the basics based on what you have included in the question. You should probably make the `Rating` and enum and/or add a `[Required]` validation attribute to ensure a rating is selected for each sub question.

Comment: Hi Stephen, thanks alot for your answer. Will take it as reference. Anyway, i need to retrieve the subquestion and number of radio button from database and show it to user to selected the rating. The subquestion and number of radio button is decide by the question creator. Thanks and i will try again. :)

Comment: What do you mean the _number of radio button_? That makes no sense at all. Your sub-question table will have fields `ID int` (PK), `Question int` (FK to Questions table), `Text varchar` and `Rating varchar`. The rating field will contain the value "Hate", "Like" or "Very Like" depending on which radio button was selected.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, i had get what you mean. I get an error by refer your code:"The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[RatingSystem.Models.Question]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'RatingSystem.Models.Question'. " Any hint?

Comment: Then you have not copied my code correctly - the first line of the view is `@model List<yourAssembly.QuestionVM>` (a list not a single object). You have obviously made it `@model yourAssembly.QuestionVM`

Comment: Impossible to tell because you have not shown your POST method, but it needs be `public ActionResult Edit(List<QuestionVM> model)` then you can loop through the items in `model`, initialize a new instance or your data model (or get the existing one from the database), update its properties and then save it (your need to save the data model, not the view model assuming they are not the same type). We are getting a bit off track here, so if you have further issues, you should post a new question showing the actual code and explaining the problem

Comment: Ok thanks again Stephen, will work it out again. Appreciate your help!